# Chrome does not showing width of screen as screen resize?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

This question may be very simple. Usually as we inspect an element and we re-size  browser ,browser automatically shows the width of screen.Currently i am using `chrome` but as i inspect any element it does not show width height of screen.I am making a site responsive but my browser not showing any screen size so i am in trouble .I seach for it but i have not found any result .I also did `restores default and reload`  from setting but it has no effect.Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Ted i am using latest version  `Version 50.0.2638.0 dev-m (64-bit)`

Comment: I have this same problem and have no solution. I see you use the dev-m channel. I use the beta channel (currently Chrome version 49), so this might be an upcoming problem. I filed a bug report via chrome://help/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just updated to Chrome 49 and [learned](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/VC-nmPWJG2g) that there is indeed [a bug causing this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582421).

Answer (score 2):

Chrome show the resolution in the upper right corner, but you need to have opened web developer tools(right mouse button -> Inspect element).

You can also use chrome Toggle device mode.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example based on javascript that will tell you the current width of the window:

```
var onresize = function() 
{
  var width = window.innerWidth
  || document.documentElement.clientWidth
  || document.body.clientWidth;
  console.log(width);
}
```

Press f12 and then press Esc to see console.

Answer (score 0):

That’s very odd. I would make sure you’re on the latest version first. If that doesn’t fix it, you could try using Device Mode for responsive testing https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **dev tools open** to see the size values as you resize. I thought Chrome took out this feature but didn't realize it doesn't show unless you have dev tools open.